# PHP also keeps session cookie values immediately

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using PHP and JavaScript with an integrated code in an Ajax to post the basket in the PHP page. I'm creating a cookie on the PHP page, then the cookie is not defined, when I get to index.php. How can I do that?

#### Attempt

```
ob_start();
if($_GET){

    if($_GET["jsonsepet"] == "true") {
        if($_POST){
            $Id = $_POST["Id"];
            $renk = $_POST["renk"];
            $adet = $_POST["adet"];
            $yas = $_POST["yas"];
            //----
            $sepet = array("renk"=>$renk);
            print_r($_POST);
            setcookie('sepet['.$Id.']', $Id, time() + 86400);
            session_destroy();
            print_r($_COOKIE);
        }
        else {
            echo "error";
        }

    }


    else {
        echo "error";
    }


}      else {

    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how can I do that"? Have you made sure that the cookie is really set? What changes if you "get to index.php"?

Comment: when I go to the index file, the cookies do not keep in the system, but the same page within another management yapmassanm if you can see Cookies defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably the path, set it to the root of your web ..

```
setcookie('sepet['.$Id.']', $Id, time() + 86400);
```

change to..

```
setcookie('sepet['.$Id.']', $Id, time() + 86400, '/');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php